# Joomla opting out "~username/", so CSS, images, etc. are pointed in the wrong spot. Please help

Tags: joomla

I've made a clean install of Joomla and all settings were done correctly. However I'm not using a domain, instead I'm using a temp URL (http://IP.ADDRESS/~username/) with Joomla installed in the root public_html directory. But when I visit, no images or styles show up... and I noticed in the source all URL's are trying to use JUST http://IP.ADDRESS without the /~username/ ... so nothing is pointed in the right place.

How can I fix this?

Comment: this is not Joomla problem. This is the server problem. Try dropping .htaccess into your site root, if that does not work try modifying rewrite rules to rewrite url to correct one (add a rewrite at the end of joomla's  .htaccess to add '~username/'

Answer (score 0):

Open configuration.php located in the web root.
Find the row that says var $live_site = '';

If the var is not empty, try making it so and save it.
If it's already empty, try typing in http://ip.address/~username/